# My "loading" shimmer does not loop correctly

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend, css-animations

Here's what I'm going for:

```
/* loading shimmer, extend for a new color */
// TODO: does not loop perfectly
@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -200px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200px 0;
  }
}
.shimmer-effect {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: shimmer;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-size: 400px 100%;
}
.gray-shimmer {
    @extend .shimmer-effect;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0, #ededed, #ebebeb, #e8e8e8, #e6e6e6);
}
.blue-shimmer {
    @extend .shimmer-effect;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #005ea2, #0c5799, #135191, #174a88, #1a4480);
}
```

You can apply these classes to any element and see that, unless the element is really small, the animation doesn't complete quickly enough, and then it awkwardly restarts at a different point. I want it to always proceed to the end of the element, and then start over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "background" setting on the {color}-shimmer rule is overwriting the background-position and background-size setting of the other rules. Change the property to "background-image"

```css
/* loading shimmer, extend for a new color */
@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -200px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200px 0;
  }
}
.shimmer-effect {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: shimmer;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-size: 400px 100%;
}
.gray-shimmer {
    @extend .shimmer-effect;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0, #ededed, #ebebeb, #e8e8e8, #e6e6e6);
}
.blue-shimmer {
    @extend .shimmer-effect;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #005ea2, #0c5799, #135191, #174a88, #1a4480);
}
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shimmer-effect blue-shimmer"></div>
```